# Bases of the intitial topological structure

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set, $(Y_j,\mathfrak{D}_j)_{j\in J}$ a family of topological spaces and $(f_j:X\rightarrow Y_j)_{j\in J}$ a family of mappings. Let
$$\mathfrak{S}=\{A\subset X\ |\ (\exists j\in J)(\exists U\in\mathfrak{D}_j)(A=f^{-1}_j(U))\}$$
and $\mathfrak{B}=\{B\subset X\ |\ (\exists n\in\mathbf{N})(\exists A)(A \in\mathfrak{S}^{[1,n]}\land B=\cap_{i=1}^nA_i)\}$. Then $\mathfrak{B}$ is a base of a topology $\mathfrak{D}$ on $X$ which is the initial topological structure on $X$ for the family $(f_j)_{j\in J}$.

Now, suppose that, for each $j\in J$, $\mathfrak{B}_i$ is a base of the topology $\mathfrak{D}_i$. Define
$$\mathfrak{S}'=\{A\subset X\ |\ (\exists j\in J)(\exists U\in\mathfrak{B}_j)(A=f^{-1}_j(U))\}$$
and $\mathfrak{B}'=\{B\subset X\ |\ (\exists n\in\mathbf{N})(\exists A)(A \in\mathfrak{S}'^{[1,n]}\land B=\cap_{i=1}^nA_i)\}$.

Are $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B}'$ bases for the same topology on $X$?

Comment: To save your readers from being buried in quantifiers you could define $\mathfrak{S}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$ more perspicuously as $$\mathfrak{S}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left\{f_n^{-1}[U]:U\in\mathfrak{D}_n\right\}$$ and 
$$\mathfrak{B}=\left\{\bigcap\mathscr{F}:\mathscr{F}\subseteq\mathfrak{S}\text{ and }\mathscr{F}\text{ is finite}\right\}\,.$$

Comment: You can even go further and take subbases in all $Y_j$ and take all finite intersections of inverse images of those as a base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are. Clearly, $\mathfrak{B}$ and $\mathfrak{B'}$ are finite intersections of sets from $\mathfrak{S}$ and $\mathfrak{S'}$, respectively. Try to show that every set from $\mathfrak{S}$ is open in the topology generated by $\mathfrak{S'}$ and observe that proving this is enough.